# Copyleft for screenplay that forces film to be free

Tags: licensing, copyleft, cc-by-sa

Consider I wrote a screenplay or book and I want if someone make a film from it, share it with same license that I used (Or another free license that keeps this constraint).

Is CC BY-SA okay? Or is there some other ready copyleft license specially for films and screenplays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [licence text](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/legalcode) of CC BY-SA 3.0, it explicitly includes someone else making a film from your work:

> "Adaptation" ... includes cinematographic adaptations

I don't mention that to suggest that CC BY-SA 4.0 doesn't include such adaptations, I only note that in 4.0 it's left implicit rather than being spelled out.  However, the idea that making a film from a book or a screenplay requires a licence is pretty well understood, so I don't think anyone in the industry could, with a straight face, claim that such a film was not an adaptation.

In both cases I think the licence will do exactly what you want, ie any film made from your work will need to be made available under CC BY-SA, or a compatible licence (ie, another copyleft licence).